# Update a object field in an array

Tags: mongodb

In mondodb I want to update a field of an object within an array. The example database looks like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ad237559d30d918c89c7f46"),
    "myArray" : [
        {
            "name" : "a",
            "name2" : "a",
            "value" : 900000 //<--- instead of this...
        },
        {
            "name" : "b",
            "name2" : "b",
            "value" : 0
        }
    ]
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ad238049d30d918c89c7f47"),
    "myArray" : [
        {
            "name" : "b",
            "name2" : "b",
            "value" : 0
        },
        {
            "name" : "c",
            "name2" : "a",
            "value" : 0 //... I want to update this
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to update the last `value` field by querying `name:c` AND `name2:a`. I tried it with the following instruction, but it sets the value of the first object (name:a name2:a). Does the problem lie near the `$` char?

```
db.test.updateOne({$and:[{"myArray.name" : "c"}, {"myArray.name2" : "a"}]},
                 {$set:{"myArray.$.value" : 900000}})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do an `$elemMatch` to match the specific item in the array and then you can use the positional operator:

```
db.test.updateOne(
    { "myArray": { $elemMatch: { "name": "c", "name2"; "a" } } },
    { $set: { "myArray.$.value": 900000 } }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [arrayFilters](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/#positional-update-arrayfilters).

```
db.test.updateOne({}, {$set:{"myArray.$[element].value" : 900000}}   { 
 multi: true,
 arrayFilters: [ {$and:[{"element.name" : "c"}, {"element.name2" : "a"}]}        ]
}, 
)
```

Sorry, I have no mongodb right there to test it, the query will probably need to be tuned a little